# How to get rid of "Alarm clock" message in perl timeout?

Tags: command-line, perl

```
[user@notebook ~] time perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' 1 sleep 2
Alarm clock

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
[user@notebook ~]
```

My question: how can I get rid of that "Alarm clock" message?? I just want to terminate a process after given time with a perl oneliner..

Answer (score 4):

That message is from bash, not Perl.

One way is to run it in a subshell:

```
$ ( time perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' 1 sleep 2 )

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Seems like it's the `time` command and subshell command that do this - I had to suppress stderr output as well to avoid the `time` output.  Ended up quite messy compared to GNU `timeout` from coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a command with a timeout, you may want to try the command `timeout` and avoid reinventing the wheel:

```
timeout 2 sleep 3
```

If you get an exit code of 124, the time has run out. Otherwise, you'll get the exit code of the executed command.

It's part of the [GNU coreutils package](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), you're likely to already have it.

Comment: The point of using perl is to improve portability, as `perl` is more commonly available than `timeout`, notably on OSX, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504945/timeout-command-on-mac-os-x