# How to print different fields from different lines with AWK

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

```
Here is my sample :
PING my.host.local (10.10.10.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=2.034 ms

--- my.host.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.034/2.034/2.034/0.000 ms
```

I would like to do something like : if /64 bytes/ then print something like : "'my.host.local' is up"

The problem is when I do a regex of /64 bytes/ then I'm losing the line showing the host name "my.host.local" and therefore I can't use that field to print my final message.

how would you do this ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to store the host name:

```
awk '/^PING/ { host = $2 } /^64 bytes/ { print host " is up" }'
```

To do something if the host is down, you need to note if a response was seen, and handle both cases at the end:

```
awk '/^PING/ { host = $2 }
     /^64 bytes/ { up = 1 }
     END {
       if (up) { print host " is up" }
       else { print host " is down" }
     }'
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly however I would like to do an "else" statement but It doesn't return anything. I tried the following : ```awk '$1 == "PING" { host = $2 } $2 == "bytes" { if ($1 == 64) {print host " is up " } else { print host " is down "}  }' bad_ping.txt```

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Its working, thanks a lot . I have some trouble to understand the logic though. So yesterday I tried to understand exactly what you did to make it works. I understand that with ```'/^PING/ { host = $2 }``` we assign the variable called "host" based on the 2nd column of the record starting by "PING". Then if we match a record starting by "64 bytes" , we assign the variable up to "1" . But then I don't understand the if statement ? If "up" is "true" then we print " host is up" otherwise we print "host is down" ? is that it ?

Comment: Yes, if `up` is non-zero we print `host " is up"`, *i.e.* the value of the `host` variable (stored when we matched `/^PING/`) followed by “is up”; otherwise, `host " is down"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```bash
ping -c 1 $machine | awk '
  $1 == "PING" {host = $2}
  $2 == "bytes" {
    if ($1 == 64)
      print host " is up"
    else
      print host " did not ping 64 bytes"
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You presumably know the host already (because you used it to run `ping`) and detecting the `64 bytes` text is not necessary since you can use the exit status of `ping`:

```
myhost=my.host.local

if ping -c 1 -t 5 "$myhost" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    printf 'host %s is up\n' "$myhost"
else
    printf 'host %s does not appear to be reachable\n' "$myhost"
fi
```

This tries to ping the given host with a timeout.  It throws away any output because only the exit status of the utility is interesting.  This is used by `if` to decide which branch to take.

On FreeBSD, `-t` sets the timeout in seconds.  On Linux, `-t` sets the TTL, and `ping` waits for twice as many seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot its pretty handy to handle it this way, however for hosts down I have this following error in the output : ```./check_network.sh: line 25: 43244 Alarm clock: 14         ping -c 1 -t 5 "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1
host smttai.fsw.ca does not appear to be reachable``` . Why am I getting this "alarm clock" message ?

Comment: @VincentAury I honestly don't know, as I don't see your script or know what sort of Unix you're on.  Is this relevant: [How to get rid of "Alarm clock" message in perl timeout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104917)